# How do you debug Share Picker extensions?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-phone-7

I have registered my Phone 7 app as a [Share Picker Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967563%28VS.92%29.aspx).  It works—my app is in the list of Share options and it gets launched and I can load the chosen image.  Okay, great.

But then things go wrong in my code.  I would like to be able to debug the issues, but I can't seem to keep the debugger attached.

I cannot debug this in the simulator, since the Pictures app (and thus the Share Picker functionality) is not present in the simulator.

I cannot debug this on the phone because as soon as I pick my app from the Share list, the debugger detaches... right as my app is "launching" again.

Is it possible to attach the debugger to a running WP7 app?  Is it possible to keep the debugger attached?  Am I doing it wrong?  Any suggestions, advice or guesses are welcome because I'm tearing my hair out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. I'm unsure if that's possible. As far as I know, there's no way to attach the debugger to when the WP7 O/S starts an app (which wasn't triggered by the debugger).

Photo Share picker extensibility, music+Video hub extensibility and other O/S extensibility points seem to not play nicely with the VS debugger. Normally I resort to MessageBox.Show to debug any problems with WP7 O/S integration.

Comment: So far the answer seems to be "not possible", but it would really make my life easier.  I had been dumping debug data to a TextBox, but I'm at the point where I really need to debug interactively.

Answer (score 2):

When doing M+V hub integration (sorry, haven't done any pictures hub integration yet) I initially used a crude debug technique (Messagebox.Show, etc. - like Justin mentioned) to verify what was being passed to the `NavigationEventArgs` of `OnNavigatedTo` and wrapped the whole method in a try..catch block to learn what was going on. I then refactored the code when I knew what could be expected. (Remember OnNavigatedTo will be called when your app is launched normally too and so `e` won't be populated in the same way.)

When the app is launched from a/the hub it creates a new instance of the app and there is currently no way to connect to this for debugging while the main page is being navigated to.

Comment: Yeah, "not possible" seems to be the current answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) Connect the Device
2) Turn off Zune
3) Start C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\WPConnect\x86\WPConnect.exe

Comment: and than you can build your solution to a phone, and debug, and Photochooser task and other such tasks will work. But because you're asking "...and then what?" I guess you tried it and it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

To properly debug your application that uses the Media Library, you'll need to use the Windows Phone Connect Tool (WPConnect.exe) as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180729%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). Jaime has some additional tips on [his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/03/tips-for-debugging-wp7-media-apps-with-wpconnect.aspx).

Once you are connected, you should be able to debug your application. Fingers crossed anyway. If that doesn't help, I'll dig a bit further.

Comment: Yes, I've been doing that.  Visual Studio stops debugging at the Share Picker -> MyApp transition.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much about the WPConnect tool. The nature of your application means that you have to have it closed and the user should pick a photo. Only after that the data is returned to the application.

You should read about the [application execution model on Windows Phone 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). Also a good explanation is [available](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/15/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-1.aspx) here.

Initially, I would say that you should look at tombstoning (a good explanation [here](http://wildermuth.com/2010/08/19/Debugging_Tombstoning_in_Windows_Phone_7)) but then again, the image returned will re-start the app and won't allow you to directly attach the debugger.

Comment: That's a good read, for sure, and I had gotten most of that data accumulated in my brain from other sources.  However, yeah, really what I need is to figure out how to target the resumed process with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, looks like this is impossible...

All the answers above seem to be missing the point: I presume you're able to debug your app in the "standalone" mode (when it's launched normally), but not when it's launched via the Share Picker Extension. Am I write? This is the wall I'm hitting... :-(

I thought the proper way would be to attach to the process once it's launched.

I tried to use Debug > Attach to Process, then select Smart Device as the Transport and Windows Phone Device as the Qualifier... But in return I get the ugly "Unable to connect to 'Windows Phone Device'. Not implemented" message.

Bummer :-(